# MySQL check if the table only contains this certain type

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, triggers, database-trigger

```
delimiter $$
CREATE Trigger TreeTest 
after insert on trees

for each row
begin
    if (select type from trees) != 'oak' OR (select type from trees ) != 'burch' OR (select type from trees ) != 'maple' OR (select type from trees ) != 'tulpin' then
 set message_text = 'You do not have the right tree';
     end if;
end; $$
delimiter ;
```

I use this code in MySQL but it always alarms the trigger with the data from the table while it shouldn't Where did I go wrong?

The goal is to check if only these three types are in the table. If not give an error.

Comment: You probably want `WHERE NOT IN (...)` instead of this long chain of comparisons. To impose a constraint consider using an `ENUM` column.

Comment: Hint: `a != x or a != y or a != z` will always have at least one returning true for `x`, `y` or `z` values as `a`. You have your logic inverted. It should be `a=x or a=y or a=z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The goal is to check if only these three types are in the table. If not give an error.

You seem to be overcomplicating this. If you want to ensure that any value given to the `type` column belongs to a predefined list, you can just use an [`ENUM` column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html), like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `trees` CHANGE `type` `type` ENUM('oak', 'burch', 'maple', 'tulpin');
```

With this setup, you can rest assured that no other value than those declared in the list will ever be allowed in the column (any attempt to provide an undeclared value would raise an error).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Change `type` column data type to ENUM('oak', 'burch', 'maple', 'tulpin')
2. Create another table with the types, put these trees there and use type_id (FK) in your table
3. Create BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE triggers instead and check if the NEW.type is not allowed to prevent adding record with the type into the table.